# Object Reference not set to an instance of object error

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-xml

Can somebody help me figure out what is wrong with the code below?

```
Messages = (
        from k in j.Descendants(xmlns + BLConst.MessageElement)
        select new KWI.Common.CLUE.BusinessEntities.Message()
        {
            type = (k.Attribute(BLConst.TypeElement) != null) ? (k.Attribute(BLConst.TypeElement).Value).ToString() : string.Empty,
            MessageText = (k.Element( xmlns + BLConst.MessageElement).Value).ToString()
        }
    ).ToList()
```

I get an error at  `select new kwi....Message(){ ..  }`

Thanks

Comment: It would have been better if you have pasted the code, then the image.

Comment: Please post the actual code (not a screenshot) and the error message in full.  That will be much more helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MessageText` selection is off - `k` is already a message element, yet you are trying to select a *child* message element from it which doesn't exist - just take the value:

```
MessageText = k.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Either `k.Attribute(...).Value` is null or `k.Element(...)` is null or `k.Element(...).Value` is null.